# Embed object to display PDF showing up as invisible

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed, element

I am using Javascript to input an embed tag to my HTML to display a pdf. The object takes up space but doesn't display anything and is essentially invisible. I tried putting it inside an object tag as well but it doesn't work.

```
// Invisible
var pdfObj = document.createElement("embed");
pdfObj.setAttribute("src", "./test.pdf");

content?.appendChild(pdfObj);
```

The pdf file does exist and when I simply put this code in the HTML it displays fine but doesn't when I use javascript.

```
// works fine
<div class="content" id="main_div">
  <embed src="../test.pdf" width="500" height="375" />
</div>
```

Here is how it shows on the HTML when I use Javascript:
[Embed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIKb0.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to make clear pathway in javascript.

```
`pdfObj.setAttribute("src", "./test.pdf");` this is your code.
`pdfObj.setAttribute("src", "../test.pdf");` this is what it needs to be.
```

and

try firstly create the element. You just gave a name to `document.createElement("embed")`. So firstly create it then setAttribute. After that it will work

If this won't work let me hear. I will help as possible as i can